# Como funciona a recompensa por Comunidade?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, recompensa

Acessando esta pergunta: [Include dentro da classe e acesso ao $this, self ou static](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76078/include-dentro-da-classe-e-acesso-ao-this-self-ou-static) é possivel ver uma recompensa de +100 Dada pelo GuilhermeNascimento e uma de +50 dada pela Comunidade (para ver é só deixar o mouse sobre a recompensa). Como funciona essa recompensa da Comunidade?

Comment: Pra mim só apareceu a minha recompensa, tentei deslogar e continua só aparecendo este texto: *Esta resposta recebeu gratificações valendo 100 reputações por Guilherme Nascimento*, talvez eu não tenha entendido bem, pode tirar uma print?

Comment: esta recompensa de +50 foi dada ao membro: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28701/henrique-schreiner

Comment: Veja parte de recompensas obtidas por ele.

Comment: A perdão entendi era na outra resposta, pensei ser na mesma :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O WallaceMaxters deu uma recompensa de 100. Mas não escolheu nenhuma resposta, então quando expirou o prazo apenas a metade da recompensa foi dada pelo Comunidade para a resposta mais votada na época. É a [regra da recompensa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/76078/revisions